# Is it possible to make donations to the Treasury?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump

In Donald Trump's [press conference](http://www.cbsnews.com/news/donald-trump-holds-first-post-election-press-conference-live-updates/) today Sherri Dillon of Morgan Lewis, a lawyer who has been working on the plan for the Trump business empire, said

> in order to ensure that “it is the American people who will profit” going forward, Mr. Trump has directed that all profits from foreign government payments made to his hotels will be **donated to the U.S. Treasury.**”

Is this possible? Has there been any precedence of any citizen (public or private) donating to a government agency in the past?

Comment: There's even a line on your 1040 form for it! Or there was the last time I looked at one.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is not unprecedented.  $2.7m was donated last year (2016).  There is even a web site specifically for donations:
https://www.treasurydirect.gov/govt/reports/pd/gift/gift.htm

Answer (score 3):

Although this already has an accepted answer, I'm posting this as additional information.

Yes it is possible, please follow [this link](https://www.pay.gov/public/form/start/23779454) to make a gift payment to the US government to reduce the public debt.

Comment: And your donation is [tax deductible](https://tax.findlaw.com/federal-taxes/charitable-contributions.html) !